# How to curve_fit an implicit scalar function using SciPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scalar

Is it possible to concatenate `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` with `scipy.optimize.bisect` (or `fsolve`, or whatever) for implicit scalar functions?

In practice, have a look at this Python code where I *try* to define an implicit function and pass it to `curve_fit` to obtain the best fit for a parameter:

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.special as spc

# Estimate of initial parameter (not really important for this example)
fact, _, _, _ = spc.airy(-1.0188)
par0 = -np.log(2.0*fact*(18**(1.0/3.0))*np.pi*1e-6)

# Definition of an implicit parametric function f(c,t;b)=0
def func_impl(c, t, p) :
    return ( c - ((t**3)/9.0) / ( np.log(t*(c**(1.0/3.0))) + p ) )

# definition of the function I believe should be passed to curve_fit
def func_egg(t, p) :
    x_st, _ = opt.bisect( lambda x : func_impl(x, t, p), a=0.01, b=0.3 )
    return x_st

# Some data points
t_data = np.deg2rad(np.array([95.0, 69.1, 38.8, 14.7]))
c_data = np.array([0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01])

# Call to curve_fit
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func_egg, t_data, c_data, p0=par0)
b = popt[0]
```

Now, I am aware of all the things that may go wrong when trying to automatically find roots (although bisection should be stable, provided there's a root between *a* and *b*); however, the error I get seems to concern the dimensionality of the output of `func_impl`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_fit.py", line 23, in <module>
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func_egg, t_data, c_data, p0=par0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 752, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 383, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 458, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "example_fit.py", line 15, in func_egg
    x_st, _ = opt.bisect( lambda x : func_impl(x, t, p), a=0.01, b=0.3 )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 550, in bisect
    r = _zeros._bisect(f, a, b, xtol, rtol, maxiter, args, full_output, disp)
  File "example_fit.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    x_st, _ = opt.bisect( lambda x : func_impl(x, t, p), a=0.01, b=0.3 )
  File "example_fit.py", line 11, in func_impl
    return ( c - ((t**3)/9.0) / ( np.log(t*(c**(1.0/3.0))) + p ) )
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My guess is that `curve_fit` basically treats the output of the input function as a vector having the same dimensionality of the input data; I thought I could easily work around this by 'vectorizing' the implicit function, or `func_egg`, although it does not seem as trivial as I thought.

Am I missing something?
Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I end up answering my own question. I hope this could be useful to others.

Let's first choose a simpler implicit function, in this case, f(c,t;b)=c-b*t^3 (the reason will be clarified later):

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.special as spc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# Definition of an implicit parametric function f(c,t;b)=0
def func_impl(c, t, p) :
    return (c-p*t**3)
```

Let's vectorize it:

```python
v_func_impl = np.vectorize(func_impl)
```

The same script as the one in the question, but now (1) `func_egg` is vectorized, and (2) I use `newton` instead of `bisect` (I found it easier to provide `x0` instead of `[a,b]`):

```python
# Definition of the function I believe should be passed to curve_fit
def func_egg(t, p) :
    x_st = opt.newton( lambda x : func_impl(x, t, p), x0=0.05 )
    return x_st
    
v_func_egg = np.vectorize(func_egg)
    
# Some data points
t_data = np.deg2rad(np.array([127.0, 95.0, 69.1, 38.8]))
c_data = np.array([0.6, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05])
    
# Call to curve_fit
par0 = 0.05
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(v_func_egg, t_data, c_data, p0=par0)
b = popt[0]
```

Now it works!

```python
plt.plot(t_data, c_data)
plt.plot(np.linspace(0.5, 2.5), b*np.linspace(0.5, 2.5)**3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

So, in essence:

- In order to concatenate `scipy` curve-fitting and root-finding one needs to ensure that each function is vectorized (or can deal with `numpy` arrays as input and output).
- Make sure that your function is not 'too ugly', otherwise even if the concatenation works the root-finding procedure itself may not be able to find a result (this goes into numerical mathematics; I should have checked the regularity of my original function).